# Basic mapping reductions without using Turing machines

Tags: reductions, computation-models

I have problems with the basics of mapping reductions.

I can understand how to do reductions using a Turing machine, but without it, I get a little bit confused.

For example:

1. How do I do a mapping reduction from $a$ to $b$, where $a$ is $\{0,1\}$ and $b$ is $\{0\}$ over the alphabet of $\{0,1\}$?
2. Does every language have a reduction to itself?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "reduction" and "mapping reduction"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity function is a reduction from a language to itself. One reduction from $\{0,1\}$ to $\{0,1\}$ is given by $\lfloor x/2 \rfloor$, which maps $0,1$ to $0$, and all other integers to non-zero values.

Comment: I am over the Alphabet of {0,1} so for input x = 000 i need tu return an instance other then 0.
tnx

Comment: @aradona A suitable reduction would be a function $f$ which is defined to map 0 and 1 to 0 and any other input to 1.